# Как сложить значения столбца в MySQL запроссе?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Простите меня, ибо я грешен, не могу вспомнить как сложить данные в запросе!

Есть таблица, с столбцом `product_summ` нужно сложить стоимости и получить общую цену - как сделать? Помогите...

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(product_summ) as summ from ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ;
```

Отпускаю тебе твой грех. Иди и не греши. И не забывай про `group by`, если захочешь вытащить что-то не обработанное статистическими функциями.